# how to nest single quotes into single quotes?

Tags: php

I want to nest a entry pop script into header, the whole code looks like -

```
<script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert(\'Warning!\n\nClick OK to proceed.\');
});
</script>
```

And I need to nest that into the following code, in between the single quotes -

```
$snippet_b[1] = '';
```

How am I supposed to place the code?

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 3):

So? Why not just do it. Your quotes are already escaped

```
<?php
$snippet_b[1] ='
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert(\'Warning!\n\nClick OK to proceed.\');
});
</script>
';

echo $snippet_b[1];

?>
```

Comment: OP has nested `<script></script>` tags, as a sidenote.

Comment: Thanks @HAL9000, that appears to be a mistake of understanding. That `<script>` is not needed as you know.

Answer (score 2):

easiest way is to use the heredoc notation

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
$snippet_b[1] = <<<SNIPPET_B1

your code here, all quotes OK.

SNIPPET_B1;
```

Comment: Indeed, HEREDOC is the simplest way for larger blocks of text. Note that if you don't want the variables parsed, you also have NOWDOC (<<<'NOWDOC'). Same thing but no parsing. Handy for jQuery stuff :)